# Do developed countries defraud trillions of dollars from developing countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

According to [the Guardian](https://amp.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/2017/jan/14/aid-in-reverse-how-poor-countries-develop-rich-countries), rich Western countries defraud large amounts of money from poor countries, much more than they give in development aid.

> If we add theft through trade in services to the mix, it brings total net resource outflows to about \$3tn per year.
> That’s 24 times more than the aid budget. In other words, for every \$1 of aid that developing countries receive, they lose \$24 in net outflows. These outflows strip developing countries of an important source of revenue and finance for development. The GFI report finds that increasingly large net outflows have caused economic growth rates in developing countries to decline, and are directly responsible for falling living standards.

I would like to know if this article is accurate. Are the fraudulent outflows really so large?

Comment: Earlier I posted a similar, but different question on this site. As @1muflon1 suggested, I posted this new question instead of editing the former. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56789/in-what-way-do-developed-countries-steal-trillions-of-dollars-from-developing-co?noredirect=1#comment93162_56789